# Javascript lodash range on array of JSON objects not returning

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

So on the `lodash` docs this is how I understand range, `_.range(start, end)`.

So if I used `.range()` on an array of JSON objects. Like...

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'name',
  },
];
```

Lets say I had 20 objects and I did `arr._.range(5, 5);` I'd get back the 5th JSON object and 5 from there.

So I've created a map function that gives me back a list of JSON objects and I then use `range` on them, here's what I have:

```
import R from 'lodash';
const getJsonData = (offset, limit) => (
  R.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], x => ({
    title: `title ${x}`,
    subtitle: 'description',
    image_url: 'http://some-img-url.com',
    date: 'date',
    tag: 'tag',
    places: [
      {
        places: 'places',
      },
    ],
  }), R.range(offset, (limit + offset)))
);
```

So I'd call this like `getJsonData(5, 5);` but it still gives me back the full list of 20 JSON objects.

Am I misunderstanding how `range` works?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Andreas sorry, just my bad way of wording it. But the general jist is an issue with `.range()` not working and me not understanding why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you have is correct.

The `map` function from `lodash` does not accept a third parameter.

So the `range` call is not taken in account.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map

So, I suggest you to use `slice` function like this:

```
import R from 'lodash';
const getJsonData = (offset, limit) => (
    R.slice(
        R.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], x => ({
            title: `title ${x}`,
            subtitle: 'description',
            image_url: 'http://some-img-url.com',
            date: 'date',
            tag: 'tag',
            places: [
                {
                    places: 'places',
                },
            ],
        }))
    , offset, limit + offset)
);
```

Comment: Ahhh okay I see. So what I actually need to do. Is fully return the full array and then call `.range` on it. I'll give that a try :)

Comment: You can `slice` the full array. I added an example.

Comment: Awesome cheers dude! Yeah, I'm an idiot :) I'll accept your answer. One thing though, the `offset, limit + offset` is outside of the `slice`. So the update would be `})), offset, limit + offset, ), );`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer to correct the misplacement of the parenthesis.